# pass click event to Android spinner

Tags: android

I created my own widget, a LinearLayout with a TextView (label) and a Spinner.

It looks like this in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    style="@style/MySpinner>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:enabled="false"/>
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:entries="@array/thats_me_age_values"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        android:padding="8dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The LinearLayout should get all touch events so it can properly use it's style (background changes on pressed). The style sets the background attribute to this selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_focused="false"> 
         <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:visible="true">
             <corners android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
             <solid android:color="@color/dark_yellow"/>
             <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/grey"/>
         </shape>
     </item> 
     <!-- focused -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"> 
         <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:visible="true">
             <corners android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
             <solid android:color="@color/dark_yellow"/>
             <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/grey"/>
         </shape>
     </item> 
     <!-- default -->
     <item>
         <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:visible="true">
             <corners android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
             <solid android:color="@color/yellow"/>
             <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/grey"/>
         </shape>
     </item>
 </selector>
```

I have tried overriding the onInterceptTouch methode for the LinearLayout. The log messages are shown on pressed but the background does not change.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.i("TOUCH", "onTouchEvent");
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    onTouchEvent(ev);
    Log.i("TOUCH", "onInterceptTouchEvent");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you try setting an `onClickListener`on the `LinearLayout`?

Comment: I did. It does only trigger when touched in the 8dp padding.

Comment: I can think of a bunch of dodgy things you can try, like putting your `LinearLayout`in a `FrameLayout` and putting a clear `LinearLayout` over the top but hacks are never the best solution and I don't even know things like that would work

Comment: I think even that wouldn't work since the backgroundcolor needs to change when a touch starts.

Comment: Changed the question, added more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think adding android:addStatesFromChildren="true" to LinearLayout will solve your problem...  So when you click/focus your spinner linear layout will change it state to clicked/focused.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Still have to override onInterceptTouchEvent and call onTouchEvent though.

Comment: Are you sure you need to override them? I tested it a little... in wat case it's not working?

Comment: If I don't override onInterceptTouchEvent the background does not change when pressed.

Comment: it changes when pressed but you should modify your selector a little, remove android:state_focused="false" and it will change color when pressed.

Comment: That didn't work for me. Also which focus do you mean? The one with pressed or the one with just focused? Both cases caused it to fail.